# Não consigo correr código depois do ciclo for

Tags: python, loop, selenium-webdriver

Estou usando o selenium como crawler em um site. Não tenho experiência com python.

Aqui eu crio um dataframe com os dados de um `.csv`

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(
    'tabela_etickets_copa3.csv',
    columns = header
    )
```

abro o navegador, entro no site, acho os elementos e seto minhas variáveis

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("xxxxxxx")

bref = driver.find_element_by_name("ctl00$SPWebPartManager1$g_1eba1641_45a3_4029_be3a_175e90e68a47$input_manage_num_reservation")
lname = driver.find_element_by_name("ctl00$SPWebPartManager1$g_1eba1641_45a3_4029_be3a_175e90e68a47$input_manage_lastname")
botao = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='Continuar']")
```

Por fim eu rodo um loop com `for` para pegar os itens do `.csv`, insiro no site e aperto enter

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    lname.send_keys(row['PAX'].rsplit("/",1)[0] 
    botao.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    driver.close()
```

Estou tendo esse erro:

```
    botao.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

O que eu entendi aqui é que a maioria dos comandos depois do `for` não funcionam. Alguém pode me sugerir algo ?

Comment: Acho que te falta um `)` aqui: `lname.send_keys(row['PAX'].rsplit("/",1)[0]`

Comment: @LucaScobino Sua pergunta está sendo fechada porque aparentemente trata-se apenas de um erro de digitação, tal como demonstrado pelo Sergio. Você confirma se de fato é isso ou não? Se não for, por favor edite sua questão para esclarecer este ponto e evitar o fechamento (ou reabrir, caso a pergunta já tiver sido fechada).

Comment: é isso sim, pode fechar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax error quer dizer que o interpretador Python não conseguir reconhecer o seu programa como código Python válido. Normalmente isso significa que tem algum sĩmpolo ou palavra-reservada faltando (ou sobrando) no seu programa ou algum erro de indentação. Erros de sintaxe são algo que o interpretador detecta antes de tentar rodar o seu programa. Não faz diferença quais funções você chamou ou quais valores você coloca nas variáveis - esses outros possíveis erros só são detectados quando seu programa estiver rodando pra valer.

No seu caso, está faltando um `)` nessa linha:

```
lname.send_keys(row['PAX'].rsplit("/",1)[0]
```

Acho que o correto seria

```
lname.send_keys(row['PAX'].rsplit("/",1)[0])
```

A razão do erro ser apontado na linha seguinte é que o parser continua a processar o programa procurando mais argumentos para o send_keys, separados por vírgula.

```
lname.send_keys(row['PAX'].rsplit("/",1)[0]
    ,arg2, arg3)
```

Como a pŕoxima linha não começou com vírgula, ele reclamou e deu um syntax error.

Comment: realmente era isso, depois disso deu um erro no   `columns = header` quando eu carrego o .csv.